# Xml layout get de-allocated on Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I wrote my first Korlin and android app.

I create custom views like this :

```
class ViewDouble(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

  View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_view_double, this)

  // other stuff goes here, like settings colors, set text ... 


}
```

with the associated xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout_double"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_header_radius">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_content_double"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserratregular"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="12sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="5sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_later"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_holding_twice" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

On my fragment i simply inflate the layout's framgent & refer to the view like this :

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_mylayout, container, false)
        return inflated
    }
```

And i insert the view in the fragment's layout like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout_fragment_open"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_purple_pattern"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

... 


    <myapp.com.myapp.Views.ViewDouble
        android:id="@+id/view_double"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_vertical_center">
```

As kotlin does not require to bind view using findViewbyID... and then i call the code i need to this view like this:

`this.view_double.startLoadingAnimation()`
`this.view_double.whatever...`

Thing is that when my app went live on the store i get a lot of crashes because this views get null and i have no idea why, i think it is related to the app's lifecyle but i'm not sure. How can i be sure the view does not get deallocated, it is inside the xml and being displayed on the screen but once i call it is null like :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void myapp.com.myapp.Views.ViewDouble.c()' on a null object reference
```

Thank for any help.

Comment: if you're inserting view at runtime then you should use findViewById method. As it was not present when the view was inflated into the fragment

Comment: well, how can he be not present if the view is inserted in the fragment's layout xml ? The view is inflated once the fragment's layout get inflated no ? thank you.

Comment: Because kotlin builds a local view cache. So the first time a property is used, it will do a regular findViewById. But next times, the view will be recovered from the cache, so the access will be faster.

Comment: Thank you, is there a lifecycle method I should re-bind the view ? like onStop() onResume() ?

Comment: no need to re-bind, but you need to be sure to *not* call this after _onViewDestroyed()_ as the cache is there cleared (to not leak views) and it will return null. You probably just need to add null-check here (_?._)

Comment: No, I can avoid the crash using a null check, I got it, what I want is when my fragment is re-created after being destroyed I can still access the value, that's what I don't understand. Thank you.